# Adding apt-get to sudoers file

Tags: apt, sudo

I've grown tired of always invoking apt-get update and apt-get upgrade under sudo and typing my password, so I have added the following line to my /etc/sudoers file using visudo:

```
<myusername> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

Unfortunately when I invoke apt-get I am met with the following error:

```
<myusername>@sputnik:~$ apt-get update
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

I have tried to add the following (fairly obvious) line to /etc/sudoers too but to no effect

```
<myusername> ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/dpkg
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even with that configuration in `/etc/sudoers`, you will still need to use `sudo` to run `apt-get` as root.  The difference is that with proper configuration you will no longer need to type in your password.

Answer (score 4):

You added apt-get in a way that doesn't ask you for a password, but that doesn't mean apt-get would have enough privileges to run. Since you're running it without sudo, it can't lock the package system.

Try to use an alias:

```
alias apt-get='sudo apt-get'
```

If it works, you can make the alias permanent by adding it to your `.bashrc` file